# What does 'webmin' come up in the netstat/lsof listening ports?

Tags: 11.10, networking, c, webmin

I have my own server application in C, I bind my server on localhost address `127.0.0.1` and let it listen in first case on port `10000` and in second case on port `20000`. When I run command I `lsof | grep IP` in last column is: 
in the first case: `localhost:webmin (LISTEN)` 
and, in the second case: `localhost:20000 (LISTEN)`

So instead of port `10000` there is `webmin`. What does it mean? I found [this](http://webmin.com/). It says that Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix but that isn't enough clear explanation. So what webmin *exactly* mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some port numbers are often/traditionally/by default used by certain services. Port 80 is for HTTP server, port 22 is SSH, port 143 is IMAP etc. Port 10000 is traditionally used by webmin to display its management interface, while port 20000 is for webmin's web mail.

`lsof` just tries to be friendly by displaying human-readable names of services which usually use those port numbers instead of the actual numbers. In your case it is wrong.

The list of "well-known" services is stored in `/etc/services`.

Comment: You can [use the `lsof -P` option to turn off port->service lookups](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=91277).